# How get process PID in Dart (Windows) with EnumProcesses

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop, ffi

I can create function to get path from PID, but now i must get process PID.

```
String _getProcessPath(int processID) {
  var path = '';
  var hProcessHandle = OpenProcess(
      PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);
  var lpFilename =
      '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
          .toNativeUtf16();
  var nSize = MAX_PATH;

  GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcessHandle, NULL, lpFilename, nSize);
  path = lpFilename.toDartString();
  CloseHandle(hProcessHandle);
  free(lpFilename);
  return path;
}
```

I understand that first i need EnumProcesses and there i can get PID, but on dart 2.12.0 i misunderstand how call this. Few examples in internet use `allocate`, that doesn`t exist in current ffi.

`numProcesses(Pointer<Uint32> lpidProcess, int cb, Pointer<Uint32> lpcbNeeded)`

required Pointer but i dont know how create it without allocate.

Need help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allocate` was replaced with `calloc`:

```
final Pointer<Uint32> aPointer = calloc<Uint32>();
// Code using it goes here.
calloc.free(aPointer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without messing with FFI at all. Just run the Windows cmd program `tasklist` and parse the output.

(I'm not currently sitting at a Windows computer to test this, but it should be pretty close to accurate.)

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Map<String, int>> getPids() async {
  final tasklistProc = Process.run('START', ['/B', 'tasklist', '/NH', '/FO', 'csv']);
  final stream = tasklistProc.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter());
  
  final pids = <String, int>{};
  await for (var line in stream) {
    final elems = line.split(',').map((elem) => elem.replaceAll('"', '')).toList();
    
    final name = elems[0];
    final pid = int.parse(elems[1]);
//     final session = elems[2];
//     final sessionNumber = int.parse(elems[3]);
//     final memUsage = elems[4];
    
    pids[name] = pid;
  }
  
  return pids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, got it with calloc.allocate() method.